# How to validate cron-expression with giiven limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, cron-task

I need to build a cron-validator.
This is a cron expression,it means every 30 seconds.

`*/30 * * * * *`

The task is to show an error if the time is less than 30 seconds.
Example:
So if I write the following, which means, every 10 seconds,

`*/10 * * * * *`

It should show an error saying, "Please enter more than 30 seconds".
Here is example function, expression is cron expression, limit is in miliseconds, So if I pass 30 second, it should validate 30 seconds.

`function cronValidator(expression = '', limit = 30000){}`

So far, I have tried this:

```
function cronValidator(expression = '', limit = 30000) {
  // filter the number of seconds from expression
  const [seconds] = expression.match(/(\d+)/);
  // convert seconds into miliseconds
  const milisecondsInExpression = seconds * 1000;

  if (milisecondsInExpression < limit) {
    console.error(`Please enter more than ${limit / 1000} seconds.`);
  } else {
    console.log('You are good to go.');
  }
}

const cronExp = '*/31 * * * * *';

cronValidator(cronExp, 40000);
```

but it is not working, cause:

- The limit or expression can be minutes or hours. Not just seconds. It means normal regex is not enough.

Comment: That's not every 30 seconds, it's every 30 minutes.

Comment: Crontab only has minute granularity, not seconds.

Comment: There's only 5 time fields: minutes, hours, days, months, weekdays.

Comment: Please verify your cron expression whether it is valid or not. You can check it out here https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 0):

Split the input into whitespace-separated fields, and just validate the first field. And you should only check the frequency if it's in the form `*/#`.

```
let fields = expression.split(/\s+/);
let seconds = fields[0];
let split_seconds = seconds.match(/^\*\/(\d+)$);
if (split_seconds) {
    let milliseconds = split_seconds[1] * 1000;
    if (milliseconds < limit) {
        console.error(`Please enter more than ${limit / 1000} seconds.`);
    }
}
```

Comment: but limit can also be hour, day, minute.. not just milisecond.

Comment: I thought you just wanted to limit the seconds.

Comment: If they split the hours, that's more than 30 seconds, so it shouldn't be necessary to limit it.